# How do I select a row with max count doing a group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `posts` with columns (`id`, `user_name`, `thread_id`).
A user can submit multiple posts for a thread. thread to post is one to many.

I need to find out who submitted max posts per thread. So the result would be
`Max(Count)`, `user_name`, `thread_id` WHERE there will be only one row per thread_id.

The table is too huge so I wanted to get the query optimized as much as I could.

Comment: What do you have for a query so far?

Comment: Hi @DeadlyJesus, I dont have a single query. I do my manipulation in PHP which I want to get away from

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with the `group by` and `having` clauses:

```
select t.user_name, t.thread_id , count(*) as max_count
from tbl t
group by t.user_name, t.thread_id
having count(*) = ( select count(*) as ttl
                    from tbl
                    where thread_id = t.thread_id
                    group by user_name
                    order by ttl desc
                    limit 1 )
```

Comment: That will get me only one row back. I need same number of rows back as number of threads. Meaning if there are posts for 4 threads in the table, I need one row back for every thread (4 rows in total in this case)

Comment: The issue is if there are 30,000 threads, I will have to query database 30,000 times. I want to prevent that and get all result set in one query

Comment: @NileshShukla: Updated

Comment: Hi @suslov, why would you think this would work? the sub query returns one row only.

Comment: Yes I did. Gave me following error.. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as max_count
from tbl t
group by t.username, t.threadid
having count(t.*) = (' at line 1

Comment: Thanks @suslov for your help bud.

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_name, thread_id, count(*) as max
from tbl t
group by user_name, thread_id
having count(*) = (
    select count(*) as cnt /* most posts per user per thread */
    from tbl
    group by user_name, thread_id
    order by cnt desc
    limit 1
)
```

Easy workaround for system that don't have `limit` is:

```
select user_name, thread_id, count(*) as max
from tbl t
group by user_name, thread_id
having count(*) = (
    select max(cnt) from (
        select count(*) as cnt /* most posts per user per thread */
        from tbl
        group by user_name, thread_id
    ) m
)
```

Comment: it gives me an error in sql query. I also dont think it would work since sub query selects only one row

Comment: Well I'm not as familiar with MySQL but I thought you could apply the limit 1 inside a subquery. And returning a single row isn't a problem unless I misunderstand your question.

Comment: I tried both of the queries you mentioned and they both return only 1 row.

Comment: Earlier you said the first query gave you an error. Anyway, I did re-read the question and I believe that @suslov's answer is the one you want after (s)he fixed the minor syntax error of `count(t.*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a table `posts` with fields `id`, `user_name` & `thread_id`.
If you want to query which user has posted the most posts on a specific thread and the total number of his posts from a table, you can achieve that with this MySQL query:

```
SELECT user_name, thread_id, count(thread_id) 
FROM posts WHERE thread_id=1 GROUP BY user_name 
ORDER BY count(thread_id) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

It will return only one row...

Comment: Can you explain your answer please? Code-only answers are liable to be deleted because they only address the specific problem and don't help future readers and others to learn how they can apply the techniques used to their own situations.